# LEN() function does not work on a column if the column name is in a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm scanning a table, looking for the length of the longest values in each column. If I name each column, the call works. If I scan the table for each column name, place the name in a variable, and call the LEN function on it, it gives me the length of the column name.

Example:

```
enrolledTerm varchar(5)  
studentSSN varchar(9)  
fullName varchar(500) -- let's say that 'Willy W. Wonka' is the longest full name in the column at 14 characters
```

Naming each column for the LEN function will give me values of 5,9,14 (acting on the column values)

Looping through the column names, putting the name of each column into a variable, and putting the variable into the LEN function gives me values of 14,10,8 (acting on the names of each column.

I don't know how to reference the contents of a variable as SQL code instead of the contents as a string.

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE @fieldName VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE cursorField CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT name 
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.enrollment');      

OPEN cursorField;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorField INTO @fieldName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 LEN(@fieldName) AS fieldLen 
    FROM dbo.enrollment;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorField INTO @fieldName;
END;

CLOSE cursorField;
DEALLOCATE cursorField;
```

This is part of a much larger project. We're archiving fixed length records (rows) from a couple hundred mainframe files (tables). The data is being provided to me in CSV files. Microsoft SQL Server is importing the data and naming the columns just fine. Each file can have hundreds of fields (columns). The files are all grossly inefficient in space allocation. My idea is to define each database table with varchar(500), then run a query against the structure of the table, and alter the column sizes to the largest value in the column.

We will be building indexes on the tables, but the data will NEVER change. I'm doing no data validation. The source data could be incorrect for the mainframe structure, but I'll take any value and store it as is.

I've tried various ways of executing the SQL without success. I've written into temporary files. I've put the SQL into variables and executed that.

Comment: Could you share what version of SQL Server you're using?

Comment: RE: " inefficient in space allocation" - Changing from `varchar(500)` to something smaller won't save you any space in the data files as the space for variable length columns is dependent on the size of the actual data - not the declared width. Your exercise can still be beneficial for memory grants though (or determining index key size before creating indexes on them).

Comment: RE: Space consumption you would need to change datatype for that, e.g. a date stored as `yyyy-mm-dd` in a `varchar` column would take 12 bytes (10 bytes for the data and 2 for variable column overhead) vs 3 bytes as a `date` datatype

Comment: Yes, it sounds like whatever you're doing won't save you any space. Unless perhaps you're doing NVARCHAR(MAX) and it uses more space due to LOBs, but if i recall, sql server doesn't LOB until the real storage reach some sort of larger value. You might wanna take a look at DATA_COMPRESSION option for your indices though, it might enable you to save space.

Comment: @siggemannen To Martin's point, you're right that right-sizing doesn't save space, but it can still help [right-size your workload performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/162117/1186).

Comment: Asides: Using `top` without `order by` allows SQL Server to pick a row at its whim. Using `max` might be more appropriate to your purpose. If fidelity is a concern you may want to investigate differences between [`len`'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [`datalength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in terms of handling trailing blanks and `char` vs `nchar` data. If you had a variable containing a string and wanted the length what code would you write?

Answer (score 4):

You can't dynamically apply calculations to strings representing column names like that. In most cases, SQL entities (table, column, etc.) need to be known at parse time. The way you've coded it...

```
LEN(@fieldName)
```

...is literally transposed to this before the code ever runs:

```
LEN('enrolledTerm') --> 12
```

It is literally just measuring the length of your string variable.

If the table has 100 columns, I question whether you really want to output 100 *resultsets* in a cursor, all with the same column name (`fieldLen`) and an integer. Even with only three columns, how are you even going to interpret that output, especially since your cursor doesn't have an `ORDER BY` (which means who knows what order the columns will be processed)? Also your top 1 is just getting the length from some arbitrary row - did you mean to use `MAX(LEN(col))`?

Here is probably a better way, assuming SQL Server 2017 or better (always good to tell us!):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @case nvarchar(max);

SELECT @case = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(alias, N' = MAX(LEN(', bn, N'))'),N',')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT column_id, 
           alias = QUOTENAME(N'max_len_' + name), 
           bn    = QUOTENAME(name)
      FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.enrollment')
  ) AS md;

SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @case + N' FROM dbo.enrollment;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Output (for [my sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/Is7MtQnm)):

| max_len_enrolledTerm | max_len_studentSSN | max_len_fullName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 39 |

If you are unfortunate enough to be on an older version (but not so unlucky that it's before SQL Server 2012), you can do:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @case nvarchar(max);

SELECT @case = STUFF((SELECT N',' 
  + CONCAT(alias, N' = MAX(LEN(', bn, N'))')
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT column_id, 
           alias = QUOTENAME(N'max_len_' + name), 
           bn    = QUOTENAME(name)
      FROM sys.columns 
      WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.enrollment')
  ) AS md
  ORDER BY column_id FOR XML PATH(N''),
  TYPE).value(N'text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');

SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @case + N' FROM dbo.enrollment;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Same results, both testable [in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Is7MtQnm?hide=4).